# Unreal Engine 4 static mesh OnHit not triggered

Tags: static, collision-detection, collision, mesh, unreal-engine4

I have a pretty basic but specific question that I can't seem to find the answer for. I've got a Blueprint containing a static Cube mesh, BlockAll collision without Physics Simulation enabled, for one of my levels. The entire floor is padded with them.

I've got it scripted up to have an effect once the player hits it, but it only seems to work when the player jumps on it. When he walks on it directly, the OnHit event does not trigger. Does this sound at all familiar? Am I missing a basic step here?

Answer (score 0):

Got somewhat answered here by Erasio;
https://answers.unrealengine.com/questions/375634/static-mesh-doesnt-trigger-onhit.html